# Remove the [asp] tag or link the [asp] tag to either [asp-classic] or [asp.net]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request

On Stack Overflow, the [asp](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp) tag was made a synonym of [asp-classic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) since that is generally what is meant. Looking over the 8 that <s>are</s> were tagged here as [asp](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp) shows a similar pattern of usage. (though I should add that most weeks we still end up with a dozen or so that meant asp.net...)

This was done as most of the time [asp](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp) was being used by people who were unaware that there were two different technologies that that tag was referring to.

Here's some of the related discussion from the main Meta.SO:

- [Classic Re-Tag Discussion on some good ole ASP (Classic)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26870/25163)
- [Let's Ban the [ASP] Tag on StackOverflow!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84175/25163)
- [Where'd the [asp] tag go, and why did it come back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119037/25163)

I would suggest making a similar change here and removing all the [asp](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp) and changing to [asp-classic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) or [asp.net](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) as appropriate. And maybe borrowing the text from the tag wiki for [asp-classic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) and [asp.net](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net).

I'd fix it, but I'm a little short on the rep requirement... I did some suggested edits/flags for the 6 that were there.

Comment: Now that the cleanup is done, should there be a banning of the tag?

Comment: @MichaelT I would think so... it would seem the same logic applies here and it would would keep Programmers.SE consistent with Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ChrisF Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

So, the cleanup has been done.  There are no questions tagged as asp.

From [Let's Ban the [ASP] Tag on StackOverflow!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112317/213963) the next step would appear to be making it a tag synonym.

From Stack Overflow a screen shot of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

[image]

Which is probably what we should have too.

The way to do this would be to go to the [asp-classic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) tag and navigate to synonyms - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/asp-classic/synonyms

The requirements for suggesting and voting on this are:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Since I've got nothing in the asp tag for answers or questions, I can't vote on this one (or suggest it).

And asp-classic its not that highly asked of a question area - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/asp-classic/topusers so there aren't many who do have the necessary rep to cast votes.

Its probably up to a mod to do this, if it is modable.

Comment: Looks like a mod will have to do this. I've flagged the question for a moderator's attention.